# Enabled Google Contacts API not shown on Consent Screen

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, authorization, google-contacts-api, google-authentication

So I've been trying to figure out why my Google Contacts wasn't being enabled after I had enabled it on Google developer console as so:

[image]

After I had enabled it, when I log in I am able to see this knowing that the Google+ Api is working fine.

[image]

As we can see, it seems as though the Contacts API is not Authorizing the enabled Contacts API. Why is that? I would expect it to be the following image.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Its been like 2 days and I haven't got my hand on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the consent screen, I can see only the basic profile info (email address, how you're are).

Probably your app is missing to ask for additional scopes during the consent. The scope for contacts API is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly`.

Comment: So I gave you the check but am running into the error of having it access denied now from the ChallengeResult. I'm not sure why this is occurring is it because I have to have a domain and register in admin console?

Comment: Should the scope be something like this??

     `googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = "",
                Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
            };googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");`

Comment: The URL should be configured during the setup of your app in the dev console. Are you using [Google API Java Client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2) or CloudSponge[http://www.cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail/]?

Comment: I am using .Net Oauth2. The problem was that I needed to scope both userprofile prior to scoping the contacts. I thought that the userprofile was scoped at default but to get access scoping the google+ api was required.