# Why doesn't the Google Cloud Platform API Console Show Contacts API Usage Metrics?

Tags: google-contacts-api

Our app has been using the Google Contacts API via the old m8 feeds URI (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/) for several years.  Up until several months ago, usage of this API would show up in the metrics and quota graphs within the GCP cloud console under the API dashboard.

Now, the graphs are empty and have no data.  We still find api usage metrics valuable and can't figure out why they aren't showing up.

We've verified repeatedly that our API calls are indeed successful and have internal metrics on our side, but the graphs are pretty much our only way of monitoring our quota usage.

Comment: Have you checked [this SO post (Enabled Google Contacts API not shown on Consent Screen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992182/enabled-google-contacts-api-not-shown-on-consent-screen)? Also, have you followed the process specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/)?

Comment: Google's Contacts API metrics have never been that reliable for us. I'll share what I see for comparison. I do see Contacts API activity (in requests/s) on the [API dashboard](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard). I see nothing on the [Contacts API Overview](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/contacts.googleapis.com/overview) or the Quotas tab. However, I do see [usage listed for each credential](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/contacts.googleapis.com/credentials) which could help me estimate the remaining quota. Happy to compare if you want.